# JLabel and icon mac issue

Tags: java, image, macos, jlabel

so I remember about 2 years ago I had an issue with displaying an icon on a label on a mac.

I've tried to do it again this year whilst working on a project and still have the same issue. Could anyone check my code works on a different computer? Either mac or windows just so I know the code works and also if anyone has any idea why it doesn't work on mine let me know!

All that happens is the frame appears with the text and buttons but no background image.

```
public class MemoryRoom extends JPanel {
/** Background image of the menu screen */
private Image bg = new ImageIcon("memoryRoom.jpg").getImage();

/** JFrame used in the entire game */
protected JFrame app; 

public MemoryRoom(JFrame app) {
    app.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    app.setVisible(true);
    app.setSize(1150, 680);
    this.app = app;
    initialize();
    app.repaint();
}

protected void initialize() {
    //final JPanel menuScreenPanel = new JPanel();
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(1150, 680);
    setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblSelectGame = new JLabel("Please select the game you wish to play:");
    lblSelectGame.setBounds(320, 180, 600, 50);
    add(lblSelectGame);
    lblSelectGame.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 24));
    lblSelectGame.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

    JButton btnSnakesAndLadders = new JButton("Snakes and Ladders");
    btnSnakesAndLadders.setBounds(370, 250, 200, 45);
    add(btnSnakesAndLadders);

    JButton btnDansCrazyTic = new JButton("Dan's Crazy Tic Tac Toe");
    btnDansCrazyTic.setBounds(590, 250, 200, 45);
    add(btnDansCrazyTic);
    btnDansCrazyTic.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent TicTacToeEvent) {
                setVisible(false);
        }
    });
    btnSnakesAndLadders.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent SnakesAndLaddersEvent) {
                setVisible(false);
        }
    });

    app.getContentPane().add(this);
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, 1150, 680, this);
}

public static void main (String args []){
    new MemoryRoom(new JFrame());
}

}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of a “current directory”?  Are you familiar with the concept of a *relative file name?*

Comment: @VGR Yes the .java file and the image are in the same package and I've checked the path of the file I'm trying to access and its the same location thats printed out.
I'm not too sure what you mean by relative file name. I've tried with "/memoryRoom.png" too as the path just in case but that returns an error saying it doesn't exist where as this way does't throw any errors just no image is shown.

Comment: Instead of guessing, research what a current directory is.  In Unix (including OS X), a relative file name is any file name that doesn’t start with `/`, and its actual location will depend on the current directory of the process which opens such a file (in this case, the Java runtime process).  If you aren't sure, print out `Paths.get("memoryRoom.jpg").toAbsolutePath()`.

Comment: @VGR I knew which directory was being used when the program was running and I've also printed out the path using that method and the image is in that location. My problem is specifically with a mac so I'm wondering if anyone else has the same issue and if so have they got around it. I've had the problem with 2 different programs over the last year and both work fine on a windows machine. So i'm wondering what could possibly be the difference or if I've done something to affect my machine.

Comment: You are using a relative file name.  It will only work when memoryRoom.jpg is in the current directory, and the current directory depends on how and where you run the program.  If you don’t want to be dependent on the external environment, place your image file in the same location as your compiled classes, and read it with `new ImageIcon(MemoryRoom.class.getResource("memoryRoom.jpg"))`.